# On the Fly Compression for a Directory

Tags: filesystems, tar, compression, fuse

I have a directory that is always going to be storing text files that are rarely (think weekly) used.  Naturally this is a great place to use compression.  However, rather than having to use tar ever time I want to access a file, I would love it if I could "mount a compressed folder".

Lets assume the folder is called mydir

Ideally the following should be true:

- Items copied/moved/deleted/read in mydir without programs needing to know that the directory is compressed
- When a file from mydir is read by a program, only that file is decompressed, not the entire directory.
- The directory should be always available.  (maybe mounted on boot or login)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If read-only access is acceptable, then [SquashFS](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) is a good choice.

However, it sounds like you want to be able to do in place updating as well. [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) may be an option for you. It is still considered somewhat experimental, but it does support [transparent file compression](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression), and is available to try in most distros.

The other approach is to do this in userspace, via [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). The most plausible of the options here is probably [fusecompress](http://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/).